# Error in ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES

Tags: postgresql, permissions, amazon-rds, role, aurora

I'm trying to create a new user in AWS Aurora Postgres DB.

Create user worked fine and I can login to the DB using that account.
granting permissions to it isn't.

First:

```
GRANT ALL on ALL tables in schema public to username
```

returns:

```
ERROR:  permission denied for relation some_table
```

`some_table` owner is a member of the same group the the new user.

Then, trying another grant options:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR USER username IN SCHEMA public GRANT ALL ON tables TO group this_group;
```

returns

```
ERROR:  must be member of role "username"
```

Any idea how to solve it out?

Comment: Who are you doing this stuff as?  It looks like the user doing the GRANT does not have the priv to do the GRANT.

Comment: "some_table is a member of the same group the the new user."  Table cannot be members of groups, unless that is something Aurora invented.  Do you mean the table is owned by a role which the new user belongs to?  If that is the case, why is a GRANT needed?

Comment: 1. I'm using root account for that - as root as one can be.
2. Fixed the missing word - the table owner is a member of the same group as the newly created user

Comment: I don't believe Aurora makes a true root account available to you.

Comment: cause I cannot access the data without granting the permissions.

Comment: Have you tried logging in as the table's owner, and doing the grant from there?

Comment: it solved the first problem. Thanks.
the other one is still here

Comment: For the second statement, log in as `username`, then you are trivially a member of that role.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe thanks. it worked. 
it still doesn't make sense since I created the `username` as root, but couldn't assign privileges to it.

Comment: You can (temporarily) `GRANT username TO root`, then you can run the statement.

Comment: thanks @LaurenzAlbe

Comment: and thanks to @jjanes

Comment: This article explains it very well: http://asheiduk.de/post/setup-pg-on-rds/